# Loop performance degradation

Tags: python, dictionary, pickle

I have the following code:

```
keywordindex = cPickle.load(open('keywordindex.p','rb'))#contains~340 thousand items
masterIndex = {}

indexes = [keywordindex]
for partialIndex in indexes:
    start = time.time()
    for key in partialIndex.iterkeys():
        if key not in masterIndex.keys():
            masterIndex[key]= partialIndex[key]
        elif key in masterIndex.keys():
            masterIndex[key].extend(partialIndex[key])
    cPickle.dump(masterIndex,open('MasterIndex.p','wb'))

    print int(time.time() - start), ' seconds'#every thousand loops
```

and I am experiencing degrading performance as the loop runs, the first 10 thousand take about 5 seconds per thousand, but every 10 thousand or so it takes another second, until its taking 3 times longer. I have tried to streamline the code in every possible way, but I can't seem to figure out what is causing it. Is there a reason for this? It's not a memory issue, I'm only at 30% usage

Comment: Why are you making a 1-element list `indexes` and then looping over it? It looks like you could scrap the outer loop entirely.

Comment: @user there is more than 1 list, I removed them for the question

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This block contains two instances of horridly inefficient coding:

```
    if key not in masterIndex.keys():
        masterIndex[key]= partialIndex[key]
    elif key in masterIndex.keys():
        masterIndex[key].extend(partialIndex[key])
```

First, the key is or is not in `masterIndex`, so there's no *useful* point at all to the `elif` test.  If the `not in` test fails, the `in` test must succeed.  So this code does the same:

```
    if key not in masterIndex.keys():
        masterIndex[key]= partialIndex[key]
    else:
        masterIndex[key].extend(partialIndex[key])
```

Second, `masterIndex` is a `dict`.  Dicts support very efficient membership testing without any help from you ;-)  By materializing its keys into a list (via `.keys()`), you're changing what *should* be a blazing fast dict lookup into a horridly slow linear search over a list.  So do this instead:

```
    if key not in masterIndex:
        masterIndex[key]= partialIndex[key]
    else:
        masterIndex[key].extend(partialIndex[key])
```

The code will run much faster then.

Comment: seeing your answers is akin to seeing a celebrity on the street.

Comment: Thank you for your clear and concise answer. I know the `elif` is bad, its leftover from earlier, but I did not know `dict`s had faster membership testing than `list`s

Comment: @ChuckFulminata, a membership test is O(1), whereas the linear search is O(n)

Comment: Thanks, @EdgarAroutiounian :-)  @ChuckFulminata, Edgar is right.  What you're doing is `O(n)` *twice over*:  first it takes `O(n)` time to *create* the list.  That's best and worst case.  Then it takes additional `O(n)` time to search the list.  That's why your code gets slower and slower over time (the number of keys keeps increasing).  Dict insertion and testing is expected case `O(1)` (constant) time independent of the number of keys.

Comment: @TimPeters I ran your code, it went through 600 thousand objects in 30 seconds, thank you

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to search through `masterIndex.keys()`. Also, just use an empty `else` clause:

```
if key not in masterIndex:
    ...
else:
    ...
```

The `in` operator on a dict queries the keys of that dict and the time complexity of that operation is O(1) on average.

Comment: the `elif` is leftover from earlier, when I needed to know exactly what was going on